# How to set focus over the first element in List view XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpf-controls

I have a list view which is placed besides a label. I want to know how we can set the focus to the first row in the list view. The Label has a shorcut key _Label (L is a shorcut key) so on pressing ALT+L my focus should be on the first row of the list view. I have been using Target= "{Binding ElementName=SomeTextBox}" for setting the focus to text box and it was just a cake walk But, in case of a list view this seems to be a problem that too selecting the first row. I want to avoid writing any logic for the same in code behing or view model. Any help will be appreciable !

Comment: Is your list always populated?

Comment: No, it may be empty..!!

Comment: OK now is it placed in the main window? Or is it in a UserControl?

Comment: It's in a user control !

Comment: Some code would be nice, I know it seems as an easy question but I don't know how your application works or even how it's structured. So if you could put the code in here and give us some indication in what container these two controls are situated. It will narrow down the possible solutions :-)